# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'QString*'

Tags: c++, qt

Basically im returning trying to return the integer counter to my main program however I get the error message of:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'QString*' [-fpermissive]
    return counter;
```

even though counter is an integer. This is probably a very simple fundamentals problem and I apologize for that but any input/explanations would be greatly appreciated.

function:

```
QString* MainWindow::sort(QString* a, int n, QString na)
{
    int yes = 1, i;
    int counter=0;
    int j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
       if (a[i] == na)
       {
                counter++;
                qDebug() << "Found a duplicate of " << a[i];
                yes = 0;
       }
    }
    if (yes)
    {
    qDebug() << "No duplicates";
    }

    qDebug() << counter;

   return counter;
}
```

Comment: Don't pass QStrings by pointer but by const reference/copy. There's almost never a reason to handle QStrings via pointers.

Comment: Ah, array. QStringList is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to return a pointer to `QString` you can create a `QString` on a free store using copy constructor which will take a `QString` created from your `counter` which is `int`:

```
QString* MainWindow::sort(QString* a, int n, QString na)
{
    int yes = 1, i;
    int counter=0;
    //...
    return new QString( QString::number( counter));
}
```

Your code couldn't compile because of lack of possibility to implicitly convert `int` to `QString`. You shouldn't however pass pointers to `QString`, just return a `QString`.

```
QString MainWindow::sort(QString* a, int n, QString na)
{
    int yes = 1, i;
    int counter=0;
    //...
    return QString::number( counter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple; your function is supposed to return a `QString *` (according to `QString* MainWindow::sort( ... )`), but you're trying to return `counter`, which is an `int` (according to `int counter = 0;`).

C++ won't implicitly convert an `int` to a `QString *` - if that's really what you want to do (**in this case, this isn't what you want to do**), you'd need to cast it explicitly, with something like `static_cast<QString *>(counter);`.

However, in your case, you've just got a mismatch, and you should decide - do you want to return counter, or do you want to return the string? In the first case, you'd change your function declaration to `int MainWindow::sort( ... )` (**This is what you said you wanted to do in your OP.**).

In the second case, instead of saying `return counter;`, you need to say `return a;` or similar. However, since the function is operating on the string in-place (i.e., not on a copy of it), this isn't really neccessary.

Comment: not true, QString can be created from int, there is no need to cast

Comment: `QString` has a static factory function which takes an `int`, but an `int` won't be implicitly converted to a **pointer to a QString** (`QString *`).

Comment: but you can do: return new QString( QString::number( counter))

Comment: Right, but the point is that I never said you can't do `int` -> `QString`. I said you can't do `int` -> `QString *` (*implicitly*).

Comment: you said "you'd need to cast it explicitly, with something like static_cast<QString *>(counter);" which is not true because you can do it also as I've just shown. Maybe better would be amend this to "you can cast it..."

Comment: `static_cast<QString *>(counter);` is **not** equivalent to `QString::number(counter);`. The first evaluates to a **pointer** to a QString, the second evaluates to a QString.

Comment: this also evaluates to pointer: return new QString( QString::number( counter));

Comment: note also that returning just a casted pointer, as you said: static_cast<QString *>(counter); will result in segmentation fault as counter is temporary variable

Comment: It returns a pointer to a new QString which contains `counter` as a string, instead of a pointer to the QString at the memory offset stored in `counter`, so they are still not equivalent. However, if the OP really wanted the value of `counter` as a string it would be valid - although I'd recommend against returning a pointer the caller needs to worry about freeing later.

Comment: Right, casting like that can segfault - although it has nothing to do with the fact that `counter` is a local variable, just that `counter`'s value, in the case of the OP, is (probably) not a valid memory address. However, in other situations, such a cast could be useful.

Comment: no, not true. Even if you have returned a pointer to a proper QString like this: QString qs; return &qs, this will result in seg fault

Comment: Right, returning a pointer to a local variable is undefined behavior. That is, however, not the same thing as casting an int to a pointer, which may work just fine (depending on the value of the int).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared as returning `QString*` and you're returning an integer. This is a mismatch.

I think the real 'fix' is to correct the function prototype to return an integer `int MainWindow::sort(QString* a, int n, QString na)` or if this isn't under your control, then you're not implementing the function right.

Comment: But what i'm using to use sort in main is sort(reallist,x,name)

Comment: But what do you intend to do with its return value? i.e. what should be the type of the returned value? That goes into the function prototype.

Answer (score 0):

An integer expression (except a constant integer expression with value 0) may not be implicitly converted to a pointer. And the error message says about this restriction.

Also it is totally unclear why you are goint to convert the counter to a QString pointer/